# Cannot assign different textures to the instances of the same object in BGE

Tags: texturing, game-engine, instances

I have a certain object, a plane in this case. What I want to do is to create instances of it at BGE runtime and assign different textures to them.

The code for the module invoked at the start

```
def init():
    '''
    MODULE
    Triggered in the beginning of the game
    '''
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    global own, scene
    own = cont.owner
    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()

    for i,texture_filename in enumerate(IMAGES):

        obj = scene.addObject('imagePlane','main')
        obj.position.z = -1000+i*0.01   
        createTexture(obj,texture_filename)
        resizeToAspect(obj,texture_filename)

    print(textures)
```

And the assigning function is basically taken from [here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bge.texture.html?highlight=texture) and slightly modded, I thought that storing every texture in separate elements of a list would help, it didn't:

```
def createTexture(obj,texture_filename):
    """Create a new Dynamic Texture"""

    # get the reference pointer (ID) of the internal texture
    #add MA in front of a material name to show that it is a MATERIAL name
    ID = texture.materialID(obj, 'MAimagePlaneMat')

    # create a texture object
    object_texture = texture.Texture(obj, ID)

    # create a new source with an external image
    url = logic.expandPath(texture_filename)
    new_source = texture.ImageFFmpeg(url)

    # the texture has to be stored in a permanent Python object
    # logic.texture = object_texture

    # update/replace the texture
    object_texture.source = new_source
    object_texture.refresh(False)

    global textures
    textures += [object_texture]
```

The problem is that all the created planes show the same image - the last one in `IMAGES` list. I presume that they are all linked to the same material and therefore the same texture, and so they read data from the same source, the once assigned the last.

Is it possible to create separate textures for the same material at the runtime? Or maybe I can create separate materials at runtime, assign different textures to them and apply to instances of the plane object? Or maybe there is some other way of applying different textures to instances of a plane?

I've read in [this thread](http://www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?325609-How-set-object-s-material-and-texture-in-game-using-python-script-BGE-python) that it's not really possible, but maybe this is an obsolete info?